# What would be an equivalent of Nunit's Assert.That in Xunit?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, xunit

I know how to write this using Nunit,

```
Assert.That(exception, Is.InstanceOfType(typeof(TypeNotRegisteredException)));
```

How can I write the same thing using in Xunit, as Xunit does not have `Assert.That`.

Comment: I thing that the correct answer would explain what is the equivalent Fluent syntax for asserting results as shown on the example above. It seems that XUnit most probably does not have it, but that is the real question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be looking for:

```
Assert.IsType<TypeNotRegisteredException>(exception);
```

Let me know if this is close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I am thinking you are asking what is the equivalent of the `InstanceOfType` assert rather than the equivalent of `Assert.That`. The latter is just a better syntax that enables you to read your asserts like English.

The equivalent of `InstanceOfType` assert in Xunit is `IsType`:

```
Assert.IsType<TypeNotRegisteredException>(exception);
```

Note that the nunit equivalent is, indeed:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf<TypeNotRegisteredException>(exception);
```

(the older `IsInstanceOfType` assert is deprecated - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=typeAsserts&r=2.5.1 )